# the ipa created by command-line is smaller than create by xcode6，why？

Tags: xcode, command-line

The command-line script：

## xcodebuild

```
  xcodebuild -verbose ARCHS="armv7 arm64" VALID_ARCHS="armv7 armv7s arm64" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING=YES \
    -configuration Release PROVISIONING_PROFILE="${profilename}" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="${codesign}" \
     clean build OBJROOT=${distDir}/Obj.root SYMROOT=${distDir}/Sym.root

# ipa
appname=$(basename ${distDir}/Sym.root/Release-iphoneos/*.app*)
target_name=$(echo $appname | awk -F. '{print $1}')
mkdir -p $project_path/package/Products
xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "${distDir}/Sym.root/Release-iphoneos/${target_name}.app" -o "$project_path/package/Products/${ipaName}" --embed "${profile}"
```

And the result is: command-line's ipa is 8M smaller than xcode one, Why?

Comment: Are you running the same build through Xcode, i.e. Release?

Comment: yes,Release package and the same build through Xcode. When I unzip the ipa file, I found the ipa created by Xcode has symbols files but command-line's ipa not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, ipa files generated from the command line are not identical to those from the Xcode app.

As you already noted, the command line one has a few missing items.

In addition to `Symbols`, if your app is written in Swift, there will be a `SwiftSupport` folder with a few libraries in the ipa generated by the Xcode app but not the command line one. Similarly, if your app includes a Watch App, there will be a missing `WatchKitSupport` folder.

Some of these missing items will be problematic when it comes to uploading an ipa to iTunes Connect. You will find numerous posts about these issues and the workarounds being adopted - but it all boils down to this issue of command line builds lacking all the required content for app distribution.

Luckily, the new version of `xcodebuild` within Xcode 7 has a solution to most of these issues but is not yet documented. Here's [some details](http://www.matrixprojects.net/p/xcodebuild-export-options-plist) on it if you are interested.